# Cannot convert from 'System.Transactions.IsolationLevel' to 'System.Data.IsolationLevel'

Tags: c#, .net

Upon implementing a transaction, which is not the type of TransactionScope, how would one specify the transaction's isolation level?

Code example:

```
public bool CreateSale(Sale sale)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool isSuccessful = false;

    using (SqlConnection connection = DBConnection.OpenConnection())
    {
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        using (SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
            cmd.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO Sale(total_price, customer_id) OUTPUT INSERTED.id VALUES (@p1, @p2);";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", sale.TotalPrice);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", sale.Customer.Id);
            sale.Id = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            count = _salesLineDB.CreateSalesLinesWithForLoop(sale, connection); 
            if (count == sale.SalesLines.Count)
            {
                transaction.Commit();
                isSuccessful = true;
            }
            else
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }

        }
    }
    return isSuccessful;
}
```

Used the following example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ha4240h(v=vs.110).aspx

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Use must use `IsolationLevel` in `System.Data` namespace. change error line to this:

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it tells you, that there is an `System.Transactions.IsolationLevel` where a `System.Data.IsolationLevel` is expected.

You can either fix it by giving the fully qualified type, changing

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```

to

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);
```

or by tweaking your `using` statements if possible. Check if you really need `using System.Transactions;`. If not, remove it.